# String based SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with BedTypes and RoomId columns as below.

| BedType | RoomId | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Double | 4 | Andrew |
| Double | 4 | Janet |
| Double | 5 | Anne |
| Double | 5 | Robert |
| Double | 7 | Michael |
| Double | 7 | Steven |
| Triple | 8 | Howard |
| Triple | 8 | John |
| Triple | 8 | Carlos |
| Triple | 9 | Jaime |
| Triple | 9 | Giovanni |
| Triple | 9 | Rene |
| Double | 10 | Alejandra |
| Double | 10 | Pascale |
| Single | 11 | Paolo |

I received to this table with the query below;

```
SELECT B.Name 'BedType',Ro.Id'RoomId',C.FirstName From Customers C
JOIN Rooms Ro ON Ro.Id = C.RoomId 
JOIN BedTypes B ON B.Id = Ro.BedTypeId 
ORDER BY Ro.ReservationId
```

The deal I could not solve is I want to make a "String based column". If the bed type of the room is Double I want only one Double Cell, and second customer's BedType cell is going to be null, as shown in the table below.

| BedType | RoomId | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Double | 4 | Andrew |
|  | 4 | Janet |
| Double | 5 | Anne |
|  | 5 | Robert |
| Double | 7 | Michael |
|  | 7 | Steven |
| Triple | 8 | Howard |
|  | 8 | John |
|  | 8 | Carlos |
| Triple | 9 | Jaime |
|  | 9 | Giovanni |
|  | 9 | Rene |
| Double | 10 | Alejandra |
|  | 10 | Pascale |
| Single | 11 | Paolo |

I tried to write a query as below but I could not succeed so far:

```
SELECT
( 
CASE WHEN B.Id =1  THEN  (SELECT Ro.Id  ) 
WHEN B.Id =3 THEN NULL 
WHEN B.Id = 4 THEN Null 
END  )  AS Trial
,B.Name 'BedType',Ro.Id'RoomId',C.FirstName From Customers C
JOIN Rooms Ro ON Ro.Id = C.RoomId 
JOIN BedTypes B ON B.Id = Ro.BedTypeId 
ORDER BY Ro.ReservationId
```

Comment: `LAG` and a `CASE` expression is your friend. Alternatively, do this in your presentation layer.

Comment: This would be an abuse of your database. This kind of formatting should be done in the client code or reporting tool, _after_ you have returned the data from the DB. But if you must, `row_number()` partitioned by roomid can also be used to do this (`case when rn = 1 then BedType else '' end as BedType`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Thom A in comments, This can be done using the window function `lag` and `case` clause :

```
select case when lag_BedType is null then BedType else null end as BedType, RoomId, FirstName
from (
  select *, lag(BedType) over (partition by RoomId order by FirstName) as lag_BedType
  from mytable
) s
```

It can also be done using `row_number()` where only the first record per room should be filled by BedType :

```
select case when rn = 1 then BedType else null end as BedType, RoomId, FirstName
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by RoomId order by FirstName) as rn
  from mytable
) s
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6C5CmWHO)